# How to load color dynamically from resource based on 1st character of text

Tags: android

I have a list of contacts and I want to change textcolor of `ListView` item based on 1st character it has. I have taken color for [a-z] in `color.xml` and want to set it to my `TextView`. I have taken something like this.

My color.xml

```
<color name="a">#ff0000</color>
<color name="b">#00ff00</color>
<color name="c">#0000ff</color>`
```

And I want to do something like this.

```
textview1.setTextColor(
    getResources().getIdentifier("@color/" +  textview1.getText().toString().toLowerCase().charAt(0),
    null,
    getPackageName()));
```

Is there any other way to perform this? 
Can anyone suggest me ...
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: send text to `int getColorId(String text)`: In this method, get `CharAt(0)` of text and put it in `switch(charAt(0))`, in all cases from A to Z, return a color id. `case "a": return R.color.a;`. Then, `textView.setTextColor(getColorId(textView.getText()));`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code fragment in the question is the following:

```
getResources().getIdentifier("@color/" +  textview1.getText().toString().toLowerCase().charAt(0),
    null,
    getPackageName())
```

returns the **identifier** of the resource, but the value passed to the `textview1.setTextColor(...)` method should be the **color** value itself (both of them have the same `int` type, that's why it can be compiled).

The fixed solution looks like this:

```
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("@color/" +  textview1.getText().toString().toLowerCase().charAt(0),
    null,
    getPackageName());
int color = getResources().getColor(resId, theme); // or use ContextCompat.getColor(...)
textview1.setTextColor(color);
```